# Apache VirtualHost configuration & Subversion

Tags: apache, svn, configuration, virtualhost

I'm trying to configure a sub-domain for my subversion repository.
I have a VH example.fr pointing to my personal website, and I want another VH svn.example.fr to point to the repository.

However, when I try to connect to svn.example.fr, I get the front page of my website...

Here is my Apache configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /srv/example.fr
    ServerName example.fr
    ServerAlias www.example.fr

    <Directory /srv/example.fr>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName svn.example.fr

    <Location />
        DAV svn
        SVNPath /srv/svn/repo

        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Subversion repository"
        AuthUserFile /srv/svn/repo/conf/passwd

        AuthzSVNAccessFile /srv/svn/repo/conf/authz

        Require valid-user
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I don't see any problem here, but I'm sure there is.

Thanks for your help !

EDIT : The configuration file is correct. I should precise that I'm running Apache inside a Docker container. Just after creating the conf file, I restarted Apache by restarting the container. This is not the right way to do it: restarting the container does not restart the server.

So Lazy Badger was right finally, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. This is question for SU
2. **After creating VirtualHost section you have to restart Apache**
3. (Not related to network|Apache config, future trouble) Plain-text `/srv/svn/repo/conf/passwd`, used by svnserve, can't be used as Apache user-file, i.e. you have to have

> ```
> ...
> AuthUserFile /path/to/htpasswd/file
> ...
> ```

4. `DocumentRoot` for VirtualHost must be defined, svn.example.fr miss it

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I don't know what is SU. I've already restarted apache a couple of times. My passwd file is not related to svnserve and has already been used with an other configuration of Apache.

Comment: Ok, my bad, I'll do that next time. Thanks !